# square and triangle

Tags: geometry

Is there an easy to solve this problem? The method I used is extremely complicated.

A square with side length s is inscribed as shown in an equilateral triangle with side length t[image]. What is the ratio t:s? Express your answer as a decimal to the nearest thousandth.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can set $t=1$. Then

$$
\frac{s}{\frac{1-s}{2}} 
$$
is the tangent of a well known angle. Solve for $s$ and invert to get the ratio you need.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$$\frac{\frac t2 - \frac s2}{\frac t2}=\frac{s}{\frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}}$$
$$\frac{t-s}{t}=\frac{2s}{\sqrt3 t}$$
$$1-\frac st=\frac{2s}{\sqrt3 t}$$
$$1=\frac st \left(1+\frac {2}{\sqrt3} \right)$$
$$\frac ts= 1+\frac {2}{\sqrt3} $$